# How to change the bibliography toc's number page

Tags: biblatex

I'm trying to put a bibliography into my report this way:
Here is my `.tex` code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,english,french]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel} \usepackage{csquotes}% recommended in output (biblatex) 
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=alphabetic]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{bibli.bib} 
\usepackage{titletoc}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliographie}
\end{document}
```

snipped of the `.bib` file, which you can multiplicate until getting 3 pages of bibliography:

```
@book{atl1,
    label       = {Tavares et al.},
    author      = {Cristopher Tavares and Kirk Fertitta and Brent Rector and Chris Sells},
    title       = {ATL Internals},
    subtitle    = {Working with ATL 8},
    edition     = {2},
    publisher   = {Addison-Wesley Professional},
    date        = {2006-07-15},
    totalpages  = {888}
    }
```

But doing that I get in the toc as number page 81 instead of 78, knowing that the bibliography ends at the 81th page.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to add the line:

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliographie}
```

to have your bibliography in the ToC.

It suffices to call `\printbibliography` in the following manner and the page number will be the correct one:

```
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,english,french]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel} \usepackage{csquotes}% recommended in output (biblatex)
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibli.bib}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: hi, thanks for your response, but, it still the same.

Comment: @dgs Run pdflatex at least twice (or delete the `.toc` file)